How to initialize the variable length array member
It seems that we could use the zero length array member as the last member of the struct, I am wondering how to initialize the struct, for example
struct test{
     int x;
     int y[0];
};


Please read more about flexible array members.

You can't use or initialise it without allocating memory for the entire struct. If you do that with calloc() you'll set all members to 0.

A zero-length array is not a variable length array or a flexible array member. It is a GCC extension that antedates C standard support for flexible array members. To define a flexible array member, omit the size specification entirely, as in int y[];. Regarding initialization, see here and here.
